# Artifactory local nuget repository yields MethodNotAllowed error

Tags: nuget, artifactory

Trying to retrieve packages from JFrog Artifactory via Nuget.  When running "nuget restore" it marches through the sources in my nuget.config (e.g. remote, local, etc).  When it tries to fetch from the local repo, it throws MethodNotAllowed.  No errors/warnings when retrieving from other sourcesjust fine.

ex:

```
MethodNotAllowed https://{company}.jfrog.io/{company}/api/nuget/it-nuget-prd-local/nuget/Packages(Id='NLog',Version='4.5.10') 212ms
```

Thanks in advance for any help.
jason

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your config is pointing to incorrect URL i.e. with extra 'nuget' in the URL path.

Correct path should be something like below:

*https://{company}.jfrog.io/{company}/api/nuget/it-nuget-prd local/Packages(Id='NLog',Version='4.5.10')*

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was an issue with our firewall and a bug with the vendor on top of that.  Security team worked around it and all is well now.

Thanks!